# Why does not this wp_redirect work in is_single()?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, wp-redirect

I have a custom post type (portfolio) and I have to redirect a certain page (of this custom post type) to another page.

when I look at my custom post type page:

[image]

So I wrote the code as follow to redirect the above 'portfolio' page :

```
if (is_singular('2024')) {
   wp_redirect('http://mysitedomain.com/../rugby/');
}
```

but when I visit to the page (ID=2024) in front end it does not redirect to the page http://mysitedomain.com/../rugby/
why is that?

- 2024 - is a custom post type page's ID
- http://mysitedomain.com/../rugby/ - is a default 'page' type not a 'post'
  type in wp.

Comment: you should add `exit` after.

Comment: `exit` isn't necessary after redirection!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) only accept `post_type`, use [`is_single('2024')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) for specific post.

```
if (is_single(2024)) {
     wp_redirect('http://mysitedomain.com/../rugby/');
     exit();
}
```

**Update:**

Also `wp_redirect()` does not work after headers are sent. Please make sure you are redirecting before headers. So you can hook this function on `template_redirect` and put this in `functions.php`

```
function redirect_custom_page() {
   if (is_single('2024')) {
        wp_redirect('http://mysitedomain.com/../rugby/');
        exit();
   }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_custom_page');
```

Comment: yes.. I want to redirect that specific post to another page but when I visiti to that specific post it does nothing.. I mean it is not redirecting..

Comment: and I tried your answer too.. but still not working

Comment: check updated version, this should work

Comment: Please explain why downvote on this answer?

Comment: @Nefro OP shows the URL - the circled part is most likely not the post slug but the *post ID*. Maybe change it to `is_single( 2024 )` so that WP interprets it as an INT and tries to look for the ID and not the post-slug.

Comment: that update did the trick and explained.. thanks.. that works like a charm